# Why can't I edit comments on my phone?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, mobile-web, usability

I am unable to click, or even select, the ”edit” link on my comments when using the browser on my Android device.  I've seen at least one other comment mentioning this, as well.  This is true for both the mobile site and the full site.  And yes, I am sure that this happens even when the time limit for editing comments has not expired.

I presume this is a bug.  Is it?  If so, are there plans to fix it?

Please note that I can neither click the link with my fingertip *nor select it with the trackball,* and that I have attempted to do so at a wide variety of zoom levels.

Comment: The edit link shows up for the mobile site on my iPhone, but it's really, really really difficult to tap without accidentally activating "add comment" instead.

Comment: It shows on my Android phone too, but again it's very difficulty to tap - my understanding is that this is a limitation/flaw in the browsers involved. You can tap it if you force it zoom in enough first.

Comment: @awoodland I have tried zooming in maximally with no success, despite the link being noticeably larger than my fingertip.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn have you *ever* succeeded in clicking it? I have not, despite maximal zoom.

Comment: Yes, sometimes.

Comment: @Boltclock'saUnicorn ah, then I guess I'll just have to keep trying... thanks for your help.

Comment: Related, just to note that this is not new, but was the case in January too: see [Why can't I select text in comments on the mobile site while logged in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118316) And [in a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129343/how-do-i-view-spoilers-on-an-ipad#comment353628_129343) at [How do I view spoilers on an iPad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129343) some claim/agree *"tapping is how you get all the on-hover events to trigger, like the flag/vote buttons for comments"*, but not for all. A long time ago, I think I did "tap to activate" to delete/vote.

Comment: When I use the mobile site on my Android phone, I can tap the “Edit” link of a comment only when I zoom quote a lot (about 5x the original scale).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this issue up. I cannot reproduce it in the current mobile view of our sites. If you continue to have issues please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I no longer have the device I was using when I posted this question.  If I recall correctly, maximal zoom and greater persistence, inspired by some of the comments, allowed me to overcome the problem.  Recently, with my current device, I haven't noticed the problem at all (but I have also been using the mobile site rarely).