# Unable to delete my comments on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

When I swipe my comments on the full site, using a mobile browser, then a cross icon appears but I fail to tap it despite my precise attempts. Even if I zoom it to the size of my thumb and tap it to discover that it's SE's bug.

**OS:** Android 2.3.5 and 4.0.3
**Web Browser:** Default stock Android browser, Dolphin Browser HD, Dolphin Mini,  Opera Mobile
(In all combinations)

I have been facing this for over a year...

Comment: I can't reproduce. I manage to delete comments just fine. What device/version/browser are you using?

Comment: [How do I delete or flag comments using the mobile website?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100706/how-do-i-delete-or-flag-comments-using-the-mobile-website?rq=1) I wonder how you did it.

Comment: @Antony: Well, exactly as detailed in the question you've linked to. I'm not aware of any other way.

Comment: @Madara Added those details...

Comment: @Asad: That is correct, and that's what I understand from the OP's attempted behavior. (That's also what I'm doing).

Comment: @Madara, so actually you *can* reproduce when using the mobile site?  [Until over at least a year ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118316/why-cant-i-select-text-in-comments-on-the-mobile-site-while-logged-in#comment310883_118316), tapping to activate the "hover" also worked on the mobile theme, but since triggers Copy on my devices. (Android 4.1.2, both in stock browser and Chrome, and Safari on iOS 6.1.2.) (Yes, tapping comments on the *full* site works fine on those very same browsers/devices. That's not what this question/bug is about?)

Comment: Sachin, how do you swipe your comments to show that delete icon? And does that also show the flag icon? And: do you think that swiping is a feature of the browsers? (I cannot even get that delete icon to show in a default Android browser, Chrome, or Safari...)

Comment: @Arjan Web Browsers does support swipe to interact with web pages. Go to full version of site in mobile browser and do swipe.

Comment: Oh, but on the full site I just tap once to trigger the "mouse hover". I never swipe for that. But then you think the icon is too small on the full site (when used on a mobile device), and you're NOT seeing such icon on the mobile site?

Comment: @Arjan Yes, I am unable to see that icon on mobile site. And, the problem with full site isn't the size of cross icon as I have said I unable to tap even after zooming it to my thumb size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've [added a "delete" link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172428/3) to the mobile theme; in doing so, I also changed the html element used for deletion from a `<span>` to an `<a>`.

After this change, I'm able to delete from the full site theme in Chrome 18 on Android 4.2.2.  Are you still having issues?

Comment: Thanks. Working fine even with mobile theme.

Comment: But, one unexpected behaviour: After I delete a comment from mobile site, the "add comment" link disappears. To bring it again, one needs to refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we only support the standard browsers on mobile devices, it's time consuming enough dealing with their myriad versions.

Comment: You mean the standard *website*, right? If the mobile theme actually allows for deleting comments in standard *browsers*, then please answer [How do I delete or flag comments using the mobile website?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100706), as I as well have not seen an option to delete, [for over a year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118316). Earlier, I could tap to activate the "hover", but since more than a year that triggers Copy. Android 4.1.2, both in stock browser and Chrome, and Safari on iOS 6.1.2. Tapping comments on the full site works fine on those very same browsers/devices.

Comment: The problem is intact with stock web browser.

Comment: Kevin, *if* you think the mobile theme *does* support deletion of comments, then please note that the OP commented that they saw the icon only on the regular site, not on the mobile theme.