# Can't delete comment using iPhone

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, mobile-web, deleted-comments

I couldn't delete my comment using *iPhone 4* (both orientations), I was only able to edit it. However, on *iPad*, editing and deleting work normally.

**Edit:** to be more specific, 'x' button doesn't appear, but 'edit' does appear.

Device used: iPhone 4 - 6.1.2

Browser: Safari

SE: Mobile version

*SE full site works normally.*

Comment: Can you define 'couldn't'? As in the 'x' button wasn't there, or clicking it didn't do anything, or you could click it but the comment is still there?

Comment: @JonW 'x' doesn't appear, only 'edit'. I'll update my question.

Comment: I just tested against this very question, wrote a comment and was able to delete it with no issues. Iphone 4S, iOS 6.1.2. You do have to select your comment first before the X button appears, but once you select it the 'x' is there and works as expected.

Comment: What browser? iPhone can run several browsers, which of those you use exactly? Also, are you browsing the mobile version of the site, or full version?

Comment: I'm using iPhone 4 - 6.1.2 - using safari and mobile version, not the full site. @ShaWizDowArd

Comment: I'm commenting from iPhone now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "delete" link has been added after "edit" for comments on mobile.  Be careful :)

Comment: What, no confirmation dialog on the mobile site? Edit: there is, no need to panic. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd it there is no confirmation it would be annoying since i dont know where exactly my large thumb touch on my mobile

Comment: @NullPonyPointer there is, I checked on my own iPhone using Safari. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ahh i know that there is since so team is enough smart .. so that we